# sanitize input before inserting data to DynamoDb

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-dynamodb, sanitization

Currently I have created an API an using MySql is a database. But now i want to move to DynamoDB. I was using bindParam to sanitize user inputs in case while inserting data to MySql. But how to sanitize user inputs before inserting to DynamoDB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AWS PHP SDK [doesn't come with a ORM](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/04/amazon-dynamodb-libraries-mappers-and-mock-implementations-galore.html) (binding).

However, a few ORM options do appear on GitHub: [option1](https://github.com/bingjie2680/Dynamodb-ORM-php), [option2](https://github.com/raslin/Amazon-dynamo-DB-simple-ORM).

#### Explanation of DynamoDB and SQL injections

When you use DynamoDB, in the end you are making calls to the DynamoDB API (for example, `get`, `scan`, `query`). Think about them as REST API endpoints that receive JSON inputs. If I want to get an element with `hashId = X`, I must set it. I can't set an injection there (such as `'X' or 1=1`) because the API won't parse my string, and the engine will simply make an equality comparison between the input string and the attribute in question (in this case - the `hash` primary key attribute).

From Googling around, people noted that NoSQL is not automatically immune to SQL injections ([see here about MongoDB and PHP](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2010/07/mongodb-is-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-in-php-at-least/)), but as far as I know you shouldn't worry when working with DynamoDB since you build the queries as part of the API and do not send long strings to the database engine for evaluation.

Comment: I am confused about sanitization in this. will this do sanitization and help to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support SQL so you shouldn't care about SQL injection. DynamoDB doesn't parse / run your data in any way. I think you are mixing both sanitization and binding.

Comment: I am bit confused in this. can you please just guide me to right document or just a give small description for this.